# Canvas - resize image and save to a variable

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize

So, I have a browser game which is run by a canvas with dynamic dimensions(it scales to the user's window's dimensions) which takes images at various sizes, scales them according to the user's window dimensions and draws them:
(example of my resizing algo:)

https://jsfiddle.net/8o3sn9mh/55/

```
var
canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var flower = new Image();
//the src is actually local, but i put a url for example's sake
flower.src = "http://plainicon.com/dboard/userprod/2803_dd580/prod_thumb/plainicon.com-46129-128px-af2.png"
flower.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(flower,0,0,128,128, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
}
```

as you can see, I am drawing a 128x128px image and I resize it to half's the user's window. So, I was thinking - my game may do this operation every single render execution, and it may take unnecessary resizing time to perform it every time. So:

1) Does performing this resizing take more time since I use it every requestAnimationFrame?

2) Is there a way to resize my image one time, save it into a var and use it in order to save that time?

Regardless I'd like a way to save the resized image into a var in order to fit it inside canvas' createPattern method:

```
pattern = ctx.createPattern(resizedFlower, 'repeat');  //resizedFlower should be the original flower resized into half's the user's window's width + height
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your image to a canvas and then use drawImage with that canvas. For instance:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var flowerCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
flowerCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
flowerCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
flowerCtx = flowerCanvas.getContext('2d');

var flower = new Image();
//the src is actually local, but i put a url for example's sake
flower.src = "http://plainicon.com/dboard/userprod/2803_dd580/prod_thumb/plainicon.com-46129-128px-af2.png"
flower.onload = function(){
    flowerCtx.drawImage(flower,0,0,128,128, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(flowerCanvas,0,0);
}
```

Now you can reuse `flowerCanvas` and it will be whatever size you initially drew it at. You probably won't see much of a performance gain between resizing vs not resizing, although you should benchmark it to be sure.

Also you shouldn't resize everything everyframe, you can listen for a window resize event, and resize when that event fires.

Comment: Ok, so 1) why do you think there isn't any performance difference? 2)I don't think it's optimal to actually make like 40 canvases(i have a lot of images to resize) and then draw it on each one of them... is it?(Well I may use it for my createPattern method though)

Comment: "Also you shouldn't resize everything everyframe, you can listen for a window resize event, and resize when that event fires." what do you mean here? I must resize it every requestAnimationFrame since the original images are bigger/smaller than what it should actually be drawn on the canvas. i want my game's characters to be proportional to the canvas' dimensions, because they are dynamic.

Comment: 1) Ok, so I measured the performance difference https://jsperf.com/canvas-resize296923 not resizing is 2% faster. 2) It will use more memory, but there shouldn't be a big performance difference unless you're using huge images.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One request, can you answer my 2nd comment?

Comment: In regards to my final comment, I meant that if you're tying the scaling size to your window size, you only need to scale them once when the window is resized (if you're using the multiple canvas method). If you are going to draw them from the original image, yes you're correct that you will need to resize them every frame.

Comment: Ok, what you meant is: If I want better performances, I should just create x canvases to my x resized images, draw on the canvases only once, and then use the canvases variables for each requestAnimationFrame. Right?